# Debugging symbolic expressions that yield NaN values during optimization

Tags: drake

I'm using the C++ API for the precompiled Drake v1.14.0 release on Linux. I've defined a `MathematicalProgram` to fit an exponential family distribution on [X^n](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?X&space;=&space;%7B0,1%7D%5En) given some constraints. One such constraint is a total probability constraint [\log \sum_{x\in X} \exp[x^T\phi x] = 0](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Clog&space;%5Csum_%7Bx%5Cin&space;X%7D&space;%5Cexp%5Bx%5ET%5Cphi&space;x%5D&space;=&space;0) and another might be a marginal probability for one of the variables. When trying to optimize using this constraint, I get an exception: `NaN is detected during Symbolic computation`. I suspect that some intermediate result is overflowing, but it really shouldn't happen as I'm using the logsumexp trick when computing the left hand side. I'd like to inspect the values that are being used to evaluate my expression.

I tried writing a `NoisyExpression` class that inherits from `Expression` and overrides the `Evaluate()` method to print the environment argument before forwarding it to the base implementation. I then wrap the left hand side of the constraint in my `NoisyExpression` class. I was expecting that it would print the environment when it was evaluated, it seems like my function overload isn't making it into the callchain.

I've got a minimal example below that only depends on drake and gtest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

#include "drake/solvers/mathematical_program.h"
#include "drake/solvers/solve.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

namespace robot::experimental::beacon_sim {
class NoisyExpression : public drake::symbolic::Expression {
   public:
    NoisyExpression(const drake::symbolic::Expression &other, const bool is_noisy)
        : drake::symbolic::Expression(other), is_noisy_(is_noisy) {}

    double Evaluate(const drake::symbolic::Environment &env) {
        std::cout << "Evaluate" << std::endl;
        if (is_noisy_) {
            std::cout << "---------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            std::cout << env << std::endl;
        }
        return drake::symbolic::Expression::Evaluate(env);
    }

   private:
    bool is_noisy_;
};

constexpr int n_choose_k(const int n, const int k) {
    int num = 1;
    int den = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        num *= n + 1 - i;
        den *= i;
    }
    return num / den;
}

auto logsumexp(const auto &terms) {
    if (terms.size() == 1) {
        return terms[0];
    }
    const auto max_elem =
        std::accumulate(terms.begin() + 1, terms.end(), *terms.begin(), drake::symbolic::max);

    const auto sum = std::accumulate(
        terms.begin() + 1, terms.end(), exp(terms[0] - max_elem),
        [&max_elem](const auto &accum, const auto &term) { return accum + exp(term - max_elem); });

    return log(sum) + max_elem;
}

drake::symbolic::Expression compute_total_log_prob(const int n,
                                                   const drake::symbolic::Variable &phi,
                                                   const drake::symbolic::Variable &psi,
                                                   const drake::symbolic::Variable &bias) {
    const auto kth_term = [&phi, &psi, &bias](const int n,
                                              const int k) -> drake::symbolic::Expression {
        return std::log(static_cast<double>(n_choose_k(n, k))) +
               static_cast<double>(k) * phi + static_cast<double>((k - 1) * k / 2) * psi + bias;
    };

    std::vector<drake::symbolic::Expression> terms;
    terms.reserve(n);
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        terms.push_back(kth_term(n, k));
    }

    return logsumexp(terms);
}

drake::symbolic::Expression compute_marginal_log_prob(const int n,
                                                      const drake::symbolic::Variable &phi,
                                                      const drake::symbolic::Variable &psi,
                                                      const drake::symbolic::Variable &bias) {
    const auto kth_term = [&phi, &psi, &bias](const int n,
                                              const int k) -> drake::symbolic::Expression {
        return std::log(static_cast<double>(n_choose_k(n, k))) +
               static_cast<double>(k + 1) * phi + static_cast<double>((k + 1) * k / 2) * psi + bias;
    };
    std::vector<drake::symbolic::Expression> terms;
    terms.reserve(n);
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        terms.push_back(kth_term(n - 1, k));
    }

    return logsumexp(terms);
}

TEST(CorrelatedBeaconsTest, min_example) {
    drake::solvers::MathematicalProgram program;
    const auto covariance_matrix_vars = program.NewContinuousVariables(2, "covar");
    const auto &diag = covariance_matrix_vars[0];
    const auto &off_diag = covariance_matrix_vars[1];
    const auto bias_var = program.NewContinuousVariables(1, "offset");
    const auto &bias = bias_var[0];
    constexpr double P_NO_BEACONS = 0.1;
    constexpr double P_BEACON = 0.5;
    constexpr int NUM_BEACONS = 2;

    // Try to fit an exponential family distribution to two variables. Since the variables are                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    // we would like to have the following output:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    // P((0,0)) = P((0, 1)) = P((1, 0)) = P((1, 1)) = 0.25                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    // The exponential family has the form P(x) = exp(x^t @ [[phi, psi], [psi, phi]] @ x + bias)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    // For this test case, we expect that phi = psi = 0 and bias = log(0.25)
    program.AddLinearEqualityConstraint(bias, std::log(P_NO_BEACONS));
    program.AddConstraint(
        NoisyExpression(compute_total_log_prob(NUM_BEACONS, diag, off_diag, bias), false) == 0.0);
    program.AddConstraint(
        NoisyExpression(compute_marginal_log_prob(NUM_BEACONS, diag, off_diag, bias), true) ==
        std::log(P_BEACON));
    program.AddCost(diag * diag + off_diag * off_diag + bias * bias);

    std::cout << program << std::endl;
    const auto result = Solve(program);

    std::cout << result.is_success() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Diag: " << result.GetSolution(diag) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Off diag: " << result.GetSolution(off_diag) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bias: " << result.GetSolution(bias) << std::endl;
}
}  // namespace robot::experimental::beacon_sim
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest NOT to use Expression in the constraint. These constraints are evaluated with double or AutoDiffXd scalar types by the nonlinear optimization solvers. Evaluating a symbolic expression and then substitute them with double/autodiff is really slow.

I would suggest to create a new class `MyNoisyExpressionConstraint` derived from `drake::solvers::Constraint` class, and overloads the Eval function (with scalar type being double, AutoDiffXd and symbolic::Expression), then use this `MyNoisyExpressionConstraint` class for adding constraint.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It seems like creating a class that derives from `drake::solvers::Constraint` also allows me to add my own debugging code.

Before doing that, is there anyway to determine what values my expression is being evaluated with?

Comment: The best way to find the Expression that's throwing is to put a try-catch around the outermost call to `expr.Evaluate(env)`, which is probably easiest to do in your own Constraint subclass.  Another option would be to fire up your program in a debugger, put a catchpoint on the NaN throw statement, and then look back up the stack to find which expression started everything (and print it in gdb).